# AndroidVolley - Unexpected response code 500

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Accessing a specific WEB-service using postman (a chrome extension for testing WEB services) results in a successful response, but my application implementation fails at hitting the same WEB-service and reports the following error:

> E/Volley: [365] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for link I'm using

What am I missing here?
Thank you.

**My application code:**

```
 private void Uploads(final String imagePath)
{

    CustomJSONObjectRequest rq = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {

                        String success = response.getString("message");


                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Response Error", error.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("token", "$2y$10$2V.Ux6CRmHoPCs2UziaVx.e6poDbFkZE2rrGrrLO1YbGcuUnkGFSS");
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", "t@t.ru");
            params.put("name", "Abyl");
            params.put("phone", "7777777777");
            params.put("fio", "fioasiodfaisfoiaosf");
            params.put("zarplata_ot", "450000");
            params.put("zarplata_do", "800000");
            params.put("opit_raboty", "2");
            params.put("city_id", "1");
            params.put("img",imagePath);
            params.put("user_id", "73");
            params.put("description", "asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd");
            return params;
        }

    };

    VolleyController.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(rq);
}
```

Comment: 500 is a http error where it indicates you cannot reach the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Volley , you have to check some of the basic configuration . So

1. Make sure , you have created a AppController class for volley.
2. Make sure , You initialize this Appcontroller in your Android Manifest.like 
   this.

   ```
           <application android:name="app.AppController"
           android:allowBackup="true"
           android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   ```
3. Print your **params hashmap** , your **token** and your **stacktrace** also .it'll help you to identify your problem in deep and check your **Baseurl** once again

Answer (score 0):

Code 500 is a HTTP Error Code that means "Internal Server Error". So, probably the problem stays on your API's side